Optimizing the Tailwind CSS build when using Angular Material?
Tailwind CSS builds an optimized CSS file by scanning html and other source files for CSS classes used an only including the classes that are declared in the HTML file class attributes.
If we are using Angular Material how would we configure the tailwind build to ensure that classes that are applied dynamically based on component state are included in the optimized tailwind css build?
